# found '0' definitions of operator "-", cannot determine exact overloaded matching definition for "-"

Tags: vhdl

How to handle the following error in given code

> found '0' definitions of operator "-", cannot determine exact
> overloaded matching definition for "-"

code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
library STD, WORK; 
use STD.STANDARD.all;
entity sqrrootofnum is
    Port ( d : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);
         `` output : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0)
           );
end sqrrootofnum;

architecture Behavioral of sqrrootofnum is
  signal regi:STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);
  signal q:STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);
  signal j:STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0);
  signal z:STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (14 downto 0);
begin
  process(d)
  begin
    j<="01"; if d(31 downto 30) > 01 then
      regi(1 downto 0) <= d(31 downto 30)-01; q(15 downto 15)<="1";
    else
      regi(1 downto 0) <= d(31 downto 30); q(15 downto 15)<="0";
    end if;
    for k in 2 to 16 loop
      if ((regi(2*(k-1)-1 downto 0) & d(2*(k-1) downto 2*(k-1)-1))-(z(k-2  downto 0) & q(15 downto 15-(k-2)) & j)) then
        regi(2*(k-1)+1 downto 0)<= ((regi(2*(k-1)-1 downto 0) & d(2*(k-1) downto 2*(k-1)-1))-(z(k-2 downto 0) & q(15 downto 15-(k-2)) & j))
        q(15-(k-1) downto 15-(k-1)) <= "1";
      else
        regi(2*(k-1)+1 downto 0) <= (regi(2*(k-1)-1 downto 0) & d(2*(k-1) downto 2*(k-1)-1));
        q(15-(k-1) downto 15-(k-1))<="0";
      end if;
    end loop;
    output <=q;
  end process;

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: An if statement selectively executes one or more sequential statements based on the value of a condition which is Boolean expression. The condition of the if statement immediately in the for loop is not a Boolean expression. Here the "-" does not provide a Boolean value. You also can't evaluate a signal that has been assigned without an intervening wait statement suspending the process. The signals regi, q, j, and z could be variables instead. This code is not likely synthesis eligible should a condition be found that expresses a Boolean value.

Comment: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ml3QK.jpg) works, is synthesis eligible (although slow, loop statements are unrolled).

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one problem in this code but I think this specific error is being caused by this line:

```
 regi(1 downto 0) <= d(31 downto 30) - 01;
```

d is a std_logic_vector so it can't be interpreted as a number - hence you can't use the subtraction operator. You either need to declare d as unsigned or cast it to an unsigned when you do this operation.